# Get Docker hostname

Tags: docker, hostname

I am very new to Docker and trying to use it to install a software. At some point in the installation process I am ask to use "**the hostname entry in your DNS server for the docker host.**"
It is used in options like this one :

```
 --log-opt gelf-address=udp://<docker-host>:12201 \
```

I read some documentation about Docker but I am not sure to understand everything. I found out that the flag `--hostname` allows to choose the hostname inside a container but is that what I need to do ?

I tried using "localhost" as that hostname entry but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I could get the hostname of my docker host or how I could set it ?

Thanks a lot for answers ! 
Vaclav

Answer (score 1):

It wants the DNS name or IP address of the physical system that's actually running the Docker daemon.  (Or, more generally for that option, the logging daemon, which may or may not be on the same system.)  This is the sort of thing you might find by running `ifconfig` on the host.

Comment: But docker pops up different interfaces with different IP addresses. It would be helpful if it could be queried by hostname (and not necessarily the host's hostname but something that can return with the host's private 172.x.y.z address)